# AWS Laravel Unit Testing - The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, phpunit, amazon-cloudfront

I am doing unit testing for my AWS Cloudfront code using `phpunit`, if I am not testing the code in the command line, my code works perfectly fine. But if I am testing it in the command line, I am getting this error: `The security token included in the request is invalid.` I read somewhere that i need to work on [Laravel "mock"](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mocking), but I can't seem to make that work.

Here is my code:

```
$this->instance(CloudFrontService::class, \Mockery::mock(CloudFrontService::class, function ($mock) {
    $mock->shouldReceive('invalidate')->with("test.txt")->once();
}));

$r = app(CloudFrontService::class)->invalidate("test.txt");

$this->assertTrue($r);
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You're missing a `returns` method on your mocked method chain, try adding something like: `->once()->andReturns(true);`

Comment: @DigitalDrifter it still doesn't work, I am getting this error: `Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method invalidate('test.txt') from Mockery_0_ xxx_Services2_CloudFrontService should be called
   │  exactly 1 times but called 0 times.`

Comment: Sounds like it solved your first error and revealed another one :) Does it make any difference if you reorder your chained methods to: `$mock->shouldReceive('invalidate')->once()->with("test.txt")->andReturn(true);`?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter sorry, it still isn't working :)